# queryParam in URL Valid xs:anyURI

Tags: xml, url, xsd, xsd-validation

I am getting the following URL as invalid:-

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturkexternalquestion/untitled.html?color=Red&product_asin=B0100RUSI6

How to give params in URL if having more than one parameters to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&amp;` instead of `&` within XML.